# How to add Mapkit framework in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone

I am using Xcode 4 for developing a Mapkit based application. I used this in Xcode's earlier version but in xcode4 this framework is missing in framework and libraries list.

I followed Application Targets> Build phases> Link binary with libraries> '+'

Help me to find it.